# "you did not select a file to upload" messgae is showing while uploading codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to upload an image into my assets folder . I couldn't make it properly. I want to save the image with name as **"last inserted id"**.

```
   $.ajax({
                url: base_url+"register/reg_submit/",
                data: $('#career_submit_form').serialize(),//returns all cells' data
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (res) {
                    alert(res.result)
   },
```

in my controller  **reg_submit**

```
      $application_insert = $this->career->insert_student_application($personal_details,$parent_details,$other_details);

    $config['upload_path'] = './application/assets/images/user_image/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg'; 
    $config['file_name'] = $application_insert.'.jpg'; 
    $this->load->library('upload', $config); 
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
    {     
        echo $this->upload->display_errors();  

    }
```

Comment: show us ur form as well... also check this, it might help you. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-upload-files-with-codeigniter-and-ajax--net-21684

Comment: in my view     `<input   type="file" class="span5 m-wrap" name="userfile" id="article_upload" >`

Comment: how can get image from serialize(); in my controller

Comment: check the link i provided. I was able to do this from that link only...

Comment: perhaps your `form` tag doesn't contain this attribute `enctype= multipart/form-data`

Comment: please include enctype= multipart/form-data in your form after method="POST" check this for more http://w3code.in/2015/09/upload-file-using-codeigniter/

Comment: what is the use of it? pls explain

Answer (score 0):

You may use '**Jquery Form**' plugin to submit file using Ajax. [link](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

Sample Code:

```
<form id="myForm" action="comment.php" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' accept-charset='utf-8'> 
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" /> 
    File: <input type="file" name="document" /> 

    <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" /> 
</form>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 

    <script> 
        // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
            $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
                alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
            }); 
        }); 
    </script>
```